# Postgres pg gem looking for the wrong version (1.0.0) of openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, openssl, rubygems, homebrew

I have openssl 1.1.1 installed via brew, and ruby 2.7.0 installed via rbenv, but my pg gem (1.2.2) is looking for the wrong openssl.

Not sure how to fix this situation. I've been struggling with openssl in various ways in various apps for a couple of months now.

```
dlopen(/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 
9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
Reason: image not found - /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to reinstall postgres via homebrew...